# Acces of undefined property cerc

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I have this code in AS3:

```
package clase
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author cry
     */
    public class CercNegru extends MovieClip
    {
        var growthRate:Number = 2;
        cerc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,grow);

        public function CercNegru() 
        {

        }
        private function grow(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("asdda");
        }
    }

}
```

When you run this program receive error:

```
    Line 12 1120: Access of undefined property cerc.
    Line 12 1120: Access of undefined property grow.
```

I put an image to understand better :

[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, how do you define `cerc`?   is the code you've posted your document class? linked to a library object?

Comment: According to the image, `cerc` is a `MovieClip` in your stage, you have just to put `cerc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,grow);` inside the constructor of your `CercNegru`, as @BadFeelingAboutThis told you in his answer, and don't forget to save your `.as` file and recompile ...

Comment: @Cristi - did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are because in class files, all functional code needs to live inside a function.

So take this line, which is just floating in the class:

```
cerc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,grow);
```

And move into the constructor (assuming you want it to run right away when you instantiate the class):

```
public function CercNegru() 
{
    cerc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,grow);
}
```

In class files, the constructor (which is the function whose name exactly matches the class name), is what get's called you use the `new` keyword.

So doing `new CercNegru()` will call that function.

NOW, I'm also *assuming* that this class file is attached to FlashPro library object, and you have something on the timeline with an instance name of `cerc`. (if that is not the case, then that is the reason for your error)

Timeline stuff though, isn't always available in the constructor, so you may need to wait until the instance has been added to the screen.

```
public var cerc:MovieClip; //you may want to create a reference to the timeline item, so you get compile time checking

public function CercNegru() 
{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
}

private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);

    //this is the equivalent of timeline code now

    cerc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,grow);
}
```

Comment: The second error was solved ... one with "circle" not

Comment: You're sure you have something on the timeline you've attached this class to with the instance name of `cerc`, and it's on the *first* frame?

Comment: as an aside, why not just add the enter frame listener to `this` instead of `cerc` ?   The only difference would be what `e.target` would refer to in the listener

Comment: yes...It is trivial in my opinion but I do not realize what goes

Answer (score 0):

```
package clase
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    /**
    * ...
    * @author cry
    */
   public class CercNegru extends MovieClip
   {
       var growthRate:Number = 2;

       var cerc:DisplayObject; // ADD THIS

       public function CercNegru() 
       {
           cerc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,grow);
       }

       private function grow(e:Event):void
       {
           trace("asdda");
       }
    }
}
```

As the error says `cerc` is undefined. So you should define it. Assuming that your 'cerc' is a `Sprite`,

```
var cerc:Sprite;
```